# Is git merge (not squash) and rebase the same if I didn't make any local commits in a branch?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-rebase

I suppose that the commit history would be the same for both if I didn't make any local commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is both yes and no.

Suppose you've cloned a copy of the Git repository for Git (e.g., https://github.com/git/git.git).  You're on your own `master` or `main` (they both exist and always identify the same commit on GitHub now, or are meant to anyway) and have made no new commits, but Junio has added some that are now on GitHub, so you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

and then:

```
git merge
```

or:

```
git rebase
```

to merge with, or rebase on, `origin/main` or `origin/master` depending on which of these two you prefer.  (That is, your upstream of your M is your origin/M, whether M is master or main.)

- *By default*, `git merge` will do a *fast-forward* operation with the upstream.  This advances your branch to match up with the remote-tracking name.
- *In all cases*, `git rebase` will checkout the tip commit of the upstream and then "replay" (cherry-pick) the commits you've made, which are no commits at all, and then reset your branch name to point here.  This advances your branch to match up with the remote-tracking name.

So here, the answer is yes.

But note the phrase *by default* above.  Suppose you ran:

```
git config merge.ff false
```

or:

```
git config --global merge.ff false
```

at some point in the past.  Then your `git merge` command won't use the default of fast-forwarding; instead, it will create a new *merge commit*.  So now the two commands give different results.

(You did—correctly—note that `git merge --squash` won't fast-forward either, and thus will likely do something you don't want.)

If you configure `merge.ff` to `only`, a plain `git merge` will be equivalent to `git merge --ff-only`, i.e., will attempt the fast-forward operation, but if that is not possible, will fail outright.  In this mode both `git merge` and `git rebase` do the same thing for this case, but `git rebase` does something when you do have your own commits (vs `git merge --ff-only`, which fails instead).